# Sending ListView Builder data to Next Screen

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a ListView in Flutter and want to send Multiple data into Next widget, but when I add a  checkout button, it's showing 3 times because I have 3 items in my cart List so I can't add button in my ListView but when I have tried this button in bottomNavigationBar but I can't  access Listing view data. Below is the Screenshot.

Comment: https://ibb.co/4JSK019 Here is the Screenshot. I Just want to know if i can send this list item data to another class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your question, can you phrase it more clearly, try short sentences. Also make sure to add your code, if it is too large then add your GitHub, or any other public repo link so we can see the code. Final thing, I can't see any screenshots.